# SSIS execute Oracle package

Tags: oracle, ssis

How do I execute an Oracle package on SSIS? I can't seem to find a solution on the internet. The package has a SQL query which has a semi colon at the end on the query. The query runs successfully when I remove the semi colon, but fails when the semi colon is at the end of the query. What might be the problem?

Comment: I think you are stating that you have an SSIS package that queries an Oracle source. The query has a semicolon which is causing the query to fail in turn resulting in the package failure. Therefore, don't use a semicolon for an Oracle query statement terminator. If all that is right, where's the question?

Comment: Your above statement is correct. The Oracle developer told me the semi colon is needed for the query to compile, apparently the package will not compile if the semi colon is removed. The query is a bit complex with cursors as part of it.

Comment: I also don't understand the question: if you know how to fix the problem, what keeps you from doing it?

Comment: probably not the right forum to get a useful answer. Have you tried an SSIS specific site? I don't think Oracle people will be too sympathetic. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter SO is a fine site for SSIS questions from my point of view. I simply have no Oracle experience to draw upon.